# `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.ImageLayout` error

Tags: java, groovy, jai

I was running a geoscript-groovy tutorial code:

```
groovy:000> import geoscript.layer.GeoTIFF
groovy:000> format = new GeoTIFF()
groovy:000> raster = format.read(new File("raster.tif"))
```

, and got the follow errors:

```
ERROR java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
javax/media/jai/ImageLayout
```

I have limited knowledge about `JAI`. I don't know whether this is a general JDK configuration issue or an issue with groovy etc.

My questions are:

What's the cause of this error associated with `javax.media.jai.ImageLayout` and how to fix it?
 How do I verify if `javax.media.jai.ImageLayout` is really installed.

Thanks

P.S. The software environment is Ubuntu 12.04 with:

```
$java -version
java version "1.6.0_32"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (6b32-1.13.4-4ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

$groovy -v
Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.6.0_32 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
```

-- UPDATE --

I changed JDK to oracle

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

and still I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
javax/media/jai/ImageLayout
        at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader (GeoTiffFormat.java:287)
        at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat$getReader.call (Unknown Source)
```

Also, the commands I used to install Oracle JDK are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

I also did

```
sudo apt-get install libjai-core-java libjai-imageio-core-java
```

and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `javax.media.jai.ImageLayout` you need an Oracle JDK. It's not present in OpenJDK. I don't know the library you're using so I can't tell you if there is any option to e.g. inject different strategy for image manipulation. Switch to Oracle JDK and test if it works for you that way.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to Oracle JDK, and it's still giving the error. Please see the update.

Comment: Do you have jai-imageio installed in your system? In Fedora linux the packages is named jai-imageio-core

Comment: I am not sure. I have just listed the commands I used to install JDK in the update.

Comment: `jai-imageio` is not a part of JDK installation, it has to be installed separately.